# Unable to locate Secure Agent under Develop

Tags: visualforce, lightning-connect

I tried logging a case asking salesforce about this but was rejected and directed here. Can anyone here shine a light on why I don't get this option in my Setup menu?

I am attempting to follow the guidelines in this help article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_secure_agent.htm

and I am unable to comply with the step that reads:

"In Setup, click Develop | Secure Agents."

This option does not appear in my org's setup menu. Is there anything I need to activate or configure before that can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce Files Connect isn't generally available yet, per the [release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_setup.htm).

> We anticipate [Salesforce Files Connect] will be generally available in the November 2014 to January 2015 time frame.